# POST API call using APIGateway returns "Internal Server Error" in swift 4, but works everywhere else

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, lambda, swift4, aws-api-gateway

I created a nodejs lambda function in AWS and exposed it using APIGateway with methods GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE (all setup with proxy). All methods have been tested and work in AWS using APIGateway, and then outside of AWS using Postman.

First, I called the GET method for the endpoint in my Swift 4 project, and it is successful.

BUT I have tried just about everything to call the POST method in swift and cannot get it to execute successfully. This is what I am currently trying after researching online:

```
let awsEndpoint: String = "https://host/path"
    guard let awsURL = URL(string: awsEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var postUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: awsURL)
    postUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    postUrlRequest.addValue("John Doe", forHTTPHeaderField: "name")
    postUrlRequest.addValue("imageurl.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "imageUrl")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postUrlRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            guard let receivedTodo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,
                                                                                      options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                                                                                        print("Error")
                                                                                        return
                            }
        } catch let err{
            print(err)
        }
    }.resume()
```

The response I get is ["message":"Internal Server Error"]. When I look at the logs in CloudWatch they are not very descriptive. The error log for the post call is:
"Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response"

After researching this issue aws suggests to format the response in a specific way and I have updated my nodejs lambda function to mimmic this.

```
    case "POST":
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    const groupName = event.headers.name;
    const imageUrl = event.headers.imageUrl;
    var group  = {Name: groupName, ImageUrl: imageUrl, IsActive:true, Created:date, Updated:date};
    var query = "INSERT INTO Groups SET ?";
    connection.query(query,group, function (error, results, fields) {
      var responseBody = {
        "key3": "value3",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key1": "value1"
      };
      var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "my_header": "my_value"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(responseBody),
        "isBase64Encoded": true
      };
      if (error) callback(error);
      else callback(null, response)
      connection.release();
    });
  });
  break;
```

Like I said previously, this works when testing everywhere except swift 4. My GET call works with swift 4, so I do not think it is an issue with allowing anything in the info.plist but I could be wrong. I have tried just about everything, but cannot seem to get past this error.

Comment: Are you using generated Swift SDK? I believe the generated SDK is Swift 3 and not Swift 4 so there might be compatibility issues. Can you try with ObjectiveC generated SDK and check if the problem persists?

Comment: @RohanDubal I'm not using the SDK currently. I don't have any authentication to setup or anything else to add to the call. Maybe this is required with proxy, but I am pretty sure you can make the call without the sdk? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue myself. After allowing ALL log output in API Gateway for that endpoint, I found that somewhere along the way my headers were being converted to all lowercase.

'imageUrl' became 'imageurl'

It was throwing an error because in my lambda function, it could not find 'imageUrl'

I think this is a conversion that is happening in APIGateway because I have never come across this issue with swift.